# Ubuntu 22.04.3 and enable vnc-server

Tags: vnc

Using 'Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS' and sharing control enabled for vnc and rtd.

How do I enable vnc-server in every reboot automatially (without loging/auto-loging).

[Ubuntu 22.04.3 - default image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzJ80.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use systemd to do it.

Assume you already install tightvncserver and you can start vncserver using root user at command line, then you can follow the steps below to start vncserver automatically after reboot.

1. Prepare the vncserver.service file

```
cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/system/vncserver.service
[Unit]
Description=Start vncserver
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=vncserver
Environment="HOME=/root" "USER=root"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

2. Reload config

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

3. Enable and start vncserver

```
systemctl enable --now vncserver
```

4. Check status and you should similar output below

```
~# systemctl status vncserver
● vncserver.service - Start vncserver
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-10-31 16:59:48 CST; 12min ago
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18675)
     Memory: 41.0M
        CPU: 1.098s
     CGroup: /system.slice/vncserver.service
             ├─1741 Xtightvnc :1 -desktop X -auth /root/.Xauthority -geometry 1024x768 -depth 24 -rfbwait 120000 -rfbauth /root/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5901 -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/,/usr/shar>
             ├─2106 xterm -class UXTerm -title uxterm -u8 -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "X Desktop"
             └─2144 -bash

Oct 31 16:59:47 server01 systemd[1]: Starting Start vncserver...
Oct 31 16:59:48 server01 vncserver[1592]: New 'X' desktop is server01:1
Oct 31 16:59:48 server01 vncserver[1592]: Starting applications specified in /root/.vnc/xstartup
Oct 31 16:59:48 server01 vncserver[1592]: Log file is /root/.vnc/server01:1.log
Oct 31 16:59:48 server01 systemd[1]: Started Start vncserver.
```

5. Try to connect vncserver with vncclient program
6. Reboot OS and the vncserver should be started automatically

Hope it's useful for you.

Comment: Nov 06 11:41:13 sk3 systemd[1]: Starting Start vncserver...
Nov 06 11:41:13 sk3 systemd[221847]: vncserver.service: Failed to locate executable vncserver: No such file or directory
Nov 06 11:41:13 sk3 systemd[221847]: vncserver.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning vncserver: No such file or directory
Nov 06 11:41:13 sk3 systemd[1]: vncserver.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Nov 06 11:41:13 sk3 systemd[1]: vncserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 06 11:41:13 sk3 systemd[1]: Failed to start Start vncserver.

Comment: As I mentioned you should install vnvcserver like tightvncserver and start it at command line correctly first, try this:
1. Install tightvncserver
apt-get install -y tightvncserver
2. start vncserver
vncserver
3. stop vncserver
vncserver -kill :1